# C program compiles and runs on my computer but not on other machines

Tags: c

The program basically searches for strings in a given wordlist that are anagrams of the word that is input from the terminal. 
It follows the algorithm:

1. Sort all the words in the list
2. Calculate hash values of the sorted words so that all anagrams have the same hash value
3. Create the hash table and start chaining by storing the hash value, the sorted word and the actual word
4. Find the anagrams by checking the hash table

Now the problems is that it runs perfectly on my machine but not on others' computers. I am including the code here and providing a link for the wordlist. I know it is too much to ask you guys to download the word list and then compile and check but it will mean a lot if you let me know. I am running Ubuntu 11.04 with 2.6.38-13-generic-pae

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct x
{
int hashvalue;
char dictword[100];
char ascending[100];
struct x *next;
} node;

char *sortWord(char *);
//double fact(int);
void main()
{
FILE *fp1, *fp2;
char ch1;
while(ch1!='q')
{   
char *dictsort;
dictsort=(char *)malloc(100*sizeof(char));  
fp1=fopen("wordlist.txt", "r");
char ch;
int i=0;
char *sortedword;
int hashindex;
long int n;
printf("Please enter size of hashtable or press Ctrl+C to break:\n");
scanf("%ld", &n);


 node *hashtable[n];
 node *temp;
 char test1[50];
char *test;     
printf("Please enter the word to find anagrams for:\n");
scanf("%s", test1);
test=sortWord(test1);
int testhash=hashfunction(test);
printf("Hash value of word is %d\n", testhash);
for(i=0;i<1000000;i++)
{
    hashtable[i]=NULL;
}
temp=NULL;
while(!feof(fp1))
{   //printf("Seg fault here...\n");        
    //ch=getc(fp1);     
    fgets(dictsort, (100*sizeof(char)),fp1);
    //puts(dictsort);

    sortedword=(char *)malloc(sizeof(dictsort));
    sortedword = sortWord(dictsort);
    hashindex=hashfunction(sortedword);


    if(hashtable[hashindex]==NULL){ 

        hashtable[hashindex] = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        strcpy(hashtable[hashindex]->dictword,dictsort);
        strcpy(hashtable[hashindex]->ascending,sortedword);
        hashtable[hashindex]->hashvalue=hashindex;
        hashtable[hashindex]->next=NULL;        
    }else{

        temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        strcpy(temp->dictword,dictsort);
        strcpy(temp->ascending,sortedword);
        temp->hashvalue=hashindex;
        temp->next=hashtable[hashindex];
        hashtable[hashindex]=temp;
    //  free(temp);             
    }
    //printf("%s", hashtable[hashindex]->dictword);
    free(sortedword);

}

//for(i=0;i<100000;i++)
//{ 
    node *print;
    print=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    print=hashtable[testhash];
    int chk;        

    while(print!=NULL)
    {
        chk=strcmp(print->ascending,test);
        if(chk==0)              
            {
                printf("%s\n", print->dictword);
                print=print->next;
            }   

        else
        print=print->next;
    }



    free(print);

}
}

int hashfunction(char *sw){

int a=0,i=0;
int k,b,c;
int div=1000000;
int blah;
int hv;     
for(i=0;sw[i]!='\0';i++){

    a=sw[i];
    //b=sw[i+1];
    //c=sw[i+2];        
    if(a!=10&&b!=10)
    {
        k=a*fact(i);
        b=k;            

        hv+=b;  
    }

}
hv=hv%div;  
return hv;

}

char *sortWord(char *s)
{
int c, d = 0, length;
char *pointer, *result, ch;
FILE *fp;
length = strlen(s);

result = (char*)malloc(length+1);

pointer = s;

for ( ch = 'a' ; ch <= 'z' ; ch++ )
{
        for ( c = 0 ; c < length ; c++ )
        {
            if ( *pointer == ch )
            {
                    *(result+d) = *pointer;
                    d++;
            }
        pointer++;
            }
    pointer = s;
}
*(result+d) = '\0';
char *z;
z=(char *)malloc(length+1);
strcpy(z, result);

//fp=fopen("sortedlist.txt", "a");
//fprintf(fp, "%s\n", s);

//fclose(fp);

free(result);

//puts(s);
//return result;
return z;   
//free(result); 


}

int fact(int num)
{
int i;
int val=1;
for(i=num+1;i>=1;i--)
{
    val=val*i;
}

return val%1000000;
}
```

Comment: What happens on other machines? Does the program fail to compile, run but segfault, run but error, or explode the computer? You must be more specific!

Comment: Can you explain in what way it doesn't work on other computers?

Comment: Please consider re-indenting properly. Makes it easier for everyone to read (and to help you)

Comment: It gives the output perfectly in mine i.e. if I enter cinema, I get the output as iceman, cinema, anemic and so forth but the same doesn't happen on other machines. It just calculates the hash value and leaves it there. The while loop that is used to enter the hash table for searching and printing appears to be the problematic area...

Comment: "*leaves it there*" = ? The program exits without printing the result?

Comment: Yeah. it doesn't give the output that I get.

Comment: The other computer does not like `void main()` ? BTW: your usage of `feof()` is also wrong. 3) you don't test the result for fopen(). 4) it is advisable to use unsigned types for indexing and hashing.

Comment: Please format the sources you provide to us for reading in a commonly accepted, well readable way, using consistent indention.

Comment: 5) `print=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    print=hashtable[testhash];` is plain nonsense. The value you got from malloc will be lost forever. 6) don't cast malloc()s return value; it is void* and can be cast to *any* pointer type.

Comment: @wildplasser: how do you suggest I go about it? I used that to point print to the pointer with the hash value that I want and then allotted the memory to take the needed things like the word to be printed. How do you suggest I go about it??

Comment: I would start by splitting it up into separate functions. And making the hashtable global (since there is only one in your program that would be acceptable). Further: correct the obvious errors (not checking fopen(), abuse of feof(), ... The size of the hashtable could be an argument to the program, which would avoid teading it from stdin (which could be used for the input corpus, avoiding the fopen() ...)

Comment: But what is the real error with using malloc the way I did?? I still don't get it...I am using the print as a temporary pointer variable to just check, search and print...

Comment: The real error is my point 5): misusing the same variable. Plus the eof() plus more.

Comment: Do come back when you cleaned it up. BTW: prime numbers are an excellent way of encoding/detecting anagrams. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Among a lot of other things:

```
 int hv;
 /* ... */
 hv+=b;
```

`hv` is never initialized. (Well as isn't object `b` in the same function and as isn't object `ch1` is `main` function.)

Comment: THANK YOU!! That was the error with the other compilers on the other systems. The hash value seems to be coming a little different because of the non initialization. Thanks a ton!!

Comment: One thing though...Even when I wasn't intiliazing the variable, I was getting the same hash value for the anagrams like one and neo or cinema and iceman. How do you suppose that is possible? This happened on all the machines...

Comment: In practice some garbage values (like `0`) have a higher probability to appear than others.

Comment: Thanks! That cleared it up :)

Answer (score 1):

Also

```
node *hashtable[n];
// ...
printf("Hash value of word is %d\n", testhash);
for(i=0;i<1000000;i++)
{
    hashtable[i]=NULL;
}
```

What if `n < 1000000`? And what if it's larger?

Aside from that, a large VLA may overflow the stack on many systems.

Comment: I am always giving the input as 1000000... I changed it to n anyway so that is not the problem.

Comment: @plaknas But the stack size could be a problem, one million pointers need eight million bytes on a 64-bit system. That's close to the 8MB default stack size on many Linux distributions, and I think Windows has a smaller stack.

Answer (score 0):

In the future, be sure to compile with all (or almost all) of your compiler's warning-flags enabled. "Variable read without being initialized" is a very common error and most compilers would've warned you about it...